# What is causing the y-coordinate to be incorrect?

Tags: jquery, css, image, coordinates

So I've created an erb block that iterates through a set of images, and then displays div.tagged for each image at the given coordinates. In this particular case the block iterates through 4 images. What I've created below works great however the coordinates for the tags are off. Any ideas? Here's a [jsFiddle that shows the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/NF3jn/4/). Thanks in advance.

ERB:

```
<div class="container">

<% if @new_manual.present? %>
    <% n = 0 %>
    <% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
        <% n += 1 %>

        <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
            <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>


        <% o_connection = Contact.find(step.output_contact) %>
            <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
            <% cord = CordType.find(step.contact_item) %>

    <br>
<div class="main_panel">
    <div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">

        <%= o_connection.product.full_name %> uses a  <%= cord.name %> to plug into <%= i_connection.product.full_name %><br>

        <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
    <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main_panel">
    <div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <%= image_tag(o_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
    <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
    </div>  
</div>  
</div>

    <% end %>   
<% end %>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('span.i_contact').each(function() {               
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) + -125;
    console.log(ypos)
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });

    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        
});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {            
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)       
});
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.image_panel{
  float:left;
  width:600px;
  position:relative;
}
.image_panel img{
  left:0;top:0px;
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tagged {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3000;
}

.main_panel{
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: When you bring up foxguide or some other pixel measurement tool, it shows that the elements are positioning themselves exactly where you tell it to. So ... it works. Change the `data-pos-y` attribute to relocate the box

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is the parent that the `.tagged` `position: absolute` is anchoring to. A `position: absolute` element anchors to the closest parent with a `position`. In this case, that is your `.image_panel`. But your last `.image_panel` contains other text that pushes down the picture, while the `.tagged` stays in place. You should make sure there is a `position: relative` `div` around only the `img` and the tag map `div`.

However, this fixes only some of your examples. It fixes your very last one, but not your first one.